# How to create a vector prototype from a Float32Array?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var vector = function(x, y, z) {
    this[0] = x || 0;
    this[1] = y || 0;
    this[2] = z || 0;
};

vector.prototype = new Float32Array(3);

vector.prototype.getLength = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this[0],2)+Math.pow(this[1],2)+Math.pow(this[2],2));
};
```

The vector is a float32array with 3 elements. I have no idea why it doesn't work. If I run this code, I get an error: `'vec3.length' is not a function`

```
var vec3 = new vector(3,4,5);
alert(vec3.getLength());
```

---

Edit: I replaced `length` with `getLength`. Now it works everywhere except in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `length` property of `Float32Array` is *readonly*, so you can't replace it with a function. In the current draft spec, you can see this in [Section 7](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#7):

```
interface TypedArray {
    const unsigned long BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = element size in bytes;

    readonly attribute unsigned long length; // <=== Note `readonly`

    getter type get(unsigned long index);
    setter void set(unsigned long index, type value);
    void set(TypedArray array, optional unsigned long offset);
    void set(type[] array, optional unsigned long offset);
    TypedArray subarray(long begin, optional long end);
};
```

---

As of your edit:

> I replaced `length` with `getLength`. Now it works everywhere except in firefox: `(intermediate value).getLength is not a function`

Not really cool to swap out the content of the question like that. But Firefox may consider `Float32Array` objects to be non-extensible. If so, you may need to add another layer so you can have your `getLength` on the middle prototype. E.g.:

```
function protovector() {
}
protovector.prototype = new Float32Array(3); 

function vector(/* ... */) {
}
vector.prototype = new protovector();
vector.prototype.getLength = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Or just put `length` or `getLength` on instances:

```
function vector(/* ... *) {
    // this[0] = ...
    this.length = function() {
        // ...
    };
}
```

But since typed arrays are of a fixed length set at construction time, I'm not sure how much you're getting out of using `Float32Array` as a prototype in the first place.

Comment: I replaced `length` with `getLength`. Now it works everywhere except in firefox: `(intermediate value).getLength is not a function`

Comment: @defunct: Firefox may consider `Float32Array` objects to be non-extensible. If so, you may need to add another layer so you can have your `getLength` on the middle prototype. (E.g., `protovector.prototype = new Float32Array(3); vector.prototype = new protovector();` Or just put `length` or `getLength` on instances. But since typed arrays are of a fixed length set at construction time, I'm not sure how much you're getting out of using `Float32Array` as a prototype in the first place.

Comment: So there is no way to manage it in firefox? My vector is just a Float32Array with some functions.

Comment: @defunct: As I said, if you add another layer of prototype, you should be able to, since then you're not trying to augment the actual `Float32Array`.